# ¿Como hacer una subconsulta dentro de consulta Api php Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Estoy creado un Api Rest cpn php Laravel, pero tengo una inquietud. Tengo 2 tablas ya relacionadas en MySql:

- Estado
- Persona

Modelo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en los controladores al consumir el metodo `get` de cada una sale asi:

```
return response()->json(Cliente::all(),200);
```

y la respuesta en json es esta:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Prof. Kaitlin Kuhic",
    "nit": "389531851",
    "estado": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nombre": "Rosalinda Durgan",
    "nit": "512817602",
    "estado": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nombre": "Loren Tillman",
    "nit": "11167177",
    "estado": 2
  }
]
```

Y si consumo el metodo `get` del controlador de la tabla estado sal este json:

```
return response()->json(Estado::all(),200);
```

Respuesta en json:

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "nombre": "Activo"
   },
   {
       "id": 2,
       "nombre": "Inactivo"
   }
]
```

Yo lo que quiero es que me salga asi el json:

```
[
      {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "Prof. Kaitlin Kuhic",
        "nit": "389531851",
        "estado": [
               {
                 "id": 1,
                 "nombre": "Activo"
               }
           ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "nombre": "Rosalinda Durgan",
        "nit": "512817602",
        "estado": [
               {
                 "id": 1,
                 "nombre": "Activo"
               }
           ]
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "nombre": "Loren Tillman",
        "nit": "11167177",
        "estado": [
               {
                 "id": 2,
                 "nombre": "Inactivo"
               }
          ]
      }
]
```

Lo que quiero es que al llamar al `get` de personas, el controller me haga una subconsulta en el campo de estado y me traiga el estado de ese Cliente.

Comment: si ya estan relacionadas, desde las migraciones y ya esta todo en MySql listo

Comment: listo ya agrege la imagen de las relaciones, y especifique que estaban ya relacionadas

Comment: si asi estan relacionados... es que es un ejemplo simplificado, el verdadero proyecto es mucho mas grande, es como para resumir la idea de la necesidad que tengo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ya estan relacionadas, desde las migraciones.

Entiendo que has añadido la clave ajena en las migraciones.
Esto crea una relación sí, pero sólo supone una restricción a la hora de crear registros, no tiene ningún efecto a la hora de realizar consultas.

Eloquent como cualquier otro ORM, para trabajar necesita ["mapear" las relaciones que existen entre las tablas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships), de alguna manera, para poder traer registros relacionados y otras operaciones. En tu caso debes relacionar los modelos Eloquent:

```
class Client extends Model
{
    public function status()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Status::class, 'status_id');
    }
}
class Status extends Model
{
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'client_id');
    }
}
```

Ahora para traer el estado de un cliente, dentro del JSON, tienes que usar [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
return response()->json(Client::with('status')->get(),200);
```

Comment: uy, muchas gracias. Era eso exactamente lo que necesitaba